# Install Perl module

Tags: perl

I need to install the Perl module
[`Test2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test2).

As far as I could [find out](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html), the easiest way for me is to install
[`App::cpanminus`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus)
and then do

```
cpanm Module::Test2
```

But when I try to do this, I keep getting the errors

> Finding Module::Test2 on cpanmetadb failed.
>   Finding Module::Test2 () on mirror http://www.cpan.org failed.
>   Couldn't find module or a distribution Module::Test2

Am I missing something or do I need to adapt the name of the module somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of the module is `Test2`, not `Module::Test2`. So, you can install it by simply

```
cpanm Test2
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried both but somehow this works better, thanks

Answer (score 2):

- There's no need to install `App::cpanminus`. (Anyway, how did you install it, and why don't you use the method for `Test2`?)
- Where did you get the idea that the package was called `Module::Test2`? It's just `Test2`

Forget about `cpanm`; just issue

```
cpan Test2
```

and it should all work for you